# How to get my file_get_contents() function to retrieve the information from a file?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am experiencing some difficulties in getting my `file_get_contents()` function to actually work. I use Coda 2 to practice PhP, and every time I attempt to retrieve the content of a file for display, a warning shows up as follows:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(template.txt):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in - on line 9
```

On line nine, I have the following:

```
echo file_get_contents("template.txt");
```

I verified the location of the file and made sure it is in the same folder with this PHP file. Maybe there is a small detail being missed here, but this should have been working.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Note: I also tried using this function on a browser with MAMP, with no success. I am currently working from a mac, if that helps in any way.

Comment: same folder doesn't mean much. you need to check `getcwd()` and confirm that PHP is actually USING the same directory. And note that some systems are case sensitive. `template.TXT`, `TeMplaTe.tXt` are both totally different files on those systems.

Comment: *Again:* Always use absolute filepaths.

Comment: `echo` should not be in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is in the same directory, use:

```
echo file_get_contents(__DIR__."/template.txt");
```

The `__DIR__` magic constant always contains the directory path of the file where `__DIR__` is being referenced. The *current working directory* of your application, however, could be somewhere completely different.

Otherwise, as already proposed, use the absolute path of the file.